# Passing multiple objects in Drools not working

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I've created a statefull knowledge session which I'm using to insert multiple objects in the session.

```
StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = initializeDrools(runtimeDrlFile.getFilePath());

private StatefulKnowledgeSession initializeDrools(String filePath) throws Exception {
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newFileResource("E:\\drools\\" + filePath), ResourceType.DRL);
    KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
}
```

Assume I've two maps, like

```
Map<String, Object> map  = new HashMap<String, Object>();  // Assume somthing is stored in it
Map<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<String, Object>();  //   ""
```

Now I've inserted both objects into ksession and fired all rules.

```
ksession.insert(maps);
ksession.insert(map);
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

This is my drools file.

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "Category Level"

when
    $map: Map( this["CategoryCode"] == "10" && this["CategoryAmount"] >= 1000 )
then
    $map.put("Discount", String.valueOf("10.00"));
    System.out.println($map);
    System.out.println($maps);
end
```

It's showing me as

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
```

If I remove `System.out.println($maps);`, it's working correctly. If I replace all occurences of `$map` with `$maps` in drl file, its working fine too but now I'm not able to access `$map` and vice versa.

Is there anything wrong with my logic of passing multiple objects into drools?

**Update:**

After clearing the Illegal Arguments Exception,

```
import java.util.Map;

rule "Category Level"

when
    $maps: Map()
    $map: Map( this["CategoryCode"] == "10" && this["CategoryAmount"] >= 1000 )
then
    $map.put("Discount", String.valueOf("10.00"));
    System.out.println($map);
    System.out.println($maps);
end
```

Now the problem is both the `sysout` is printing the value of `$map`. Why `$maps` value is replaced with `$map`?

Comment: A declaration can only represent a single fact at a time, hence $map is just a single fact.  There is also no declaration of a $maps, so when you attempt print it out you are essentiall printing something which does not exist.

Comment: @ConMan, yup.. Now I understand..

Comment: @ConMan, I've corrected the declaration part, but strange thing is, whatever I'm storing in `$maps` in java and passed into drools, when I put `System.out.println($map); System.out.println($maps);` , both were printing the value stored in `$map`. Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like

```
$mx: Map()
```

is capable of binding any Map inserted as a fact. So, if you have a couple of patterns

```
$mx: Map()
$my: Map()
```

a single map will bind as $mx and $my. If you have two maps, a and b, they'll be bound in a fourfold way: a-a, a-b, b-a, b-b.

Adding a constraint to a pattern, e.g.,

```
$mx: Map( this["CategoryCode"] == "10" && this["CategoryAmount"] >= 1000 )
```

restricts the possible matches and bindings, but adding another pattern:

```
$mx: Map( this["CategoryCode"] == "10" && this["CategoryAmount"] >= 1000 )
$my: Map()
```

will still produce multiple matches, e.g., with two maps as facts and one of these maps matching the first pattern, you'll still get a-a, a-b.

java.util.Map and other "anonymous" container classes (maps and all Collections) are notoriously tricky for matching. If a map represents some "real world" entity, it should have an entry providing unique identification. Use this in all patterns.

Preferably, Java beans should be used as facts, with some field providing identification.

Answer (score 1):

You dont define `$maps` anywhere. You need to declare it and assign it a value.

You want something like this:

```
$map: Map( this["CategoryCode"] == "10" && this["CategoryAmount"] >= 1000 )
$maps: Map()
```

Comment: Can you explain what is `...something...` ? Because I've tried like `$maps: Map`, but it doesn't work.. UPDATE: `$maps: Map()` is working.. Thanks

Comment: Sweet! Drools will drive you insane with this stuff

Comment: Strange thing is, whatever I'm storing in `$maps` in java and passed into drools, when I put `System.out.println($map); System.out.println($maps);` , both were printing the value stored in `$map`. Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: Theyre set to the same value, you need to put some condition in Map() to differentiate it.